# Fetch call firing onChange rather than onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm building a recipe search page with React. There are two components - Navbar and Home. The Navbar takes in the search query and the Home renders the data.

The API call works fine and the recipes render as needed. The issue I'm having is whenever the user types anything in the search bar, my fetch call fires - but I need the request to fire only when the submit button is pressed.

Here's the code: (I'm using App.js as the intermediary between the two components because they're siblings)

NAVBAR

```
function Navbar({ setInput, handleSubmit }) {

  return (
  // Step 1 - User inputs query
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
       <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
     </form>
  )
}
```

APP.JS

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate('/home')
  };

  return (
  // Step 2 - App handles exchange
    <Navbar setInput={setInput} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    <Home input={input} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  )
}
```

HOME

```
function Home({ input, handleSubmit }) {

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`www.recipeAPI/${input}`)
        .then(res => //render recipes with res)
    }, [handleSubmit]);


  return (
    // Step 3 - fetch call data gets rendered
  )
}
```

I've tried all kinds of hooks and listeners but nothing seems to stop the API from calling every time a user types.

I appreciate the help in advance :/

Comment: It seems strange to use function `handleSubmit` itself in the useEffect capture. Could you fill in the commented stubs with a [mcve]? It's not really clear why `Home` needs to use that effect or why the axios call needs to be inside of it.

Comment: whenever you update a state, handleSubmit function initialises as it is a dependency of useEffect, making request to axios on every change in state i.e input.
replace [handleSubmit] with []

Comment: In the Home component, try remove handleSubmit from the dependency array of useEffect

Answer (score 1):

Whenever `App` is re-rendered, stating `input` state for example, you re-create the `handleSubmit` function. Since the `handleSubmit` function is a dependency of the `useEffect` in home, it react to the change, and a call is issued.

To prevent that wrap `handleSubmit` with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), which would memoize the function, and prevent generating a new function on each re-render.

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate('/home')
  }, []);

  return (
  // Step 2 - App handles exchange
    <Navbar setInput={setInput} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    <Home input={input} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was moving the entire fetch call to App.js and passing down the results to home. That solved the issue